# Install OpenCV for VisualStudio 2012

Tags: visual-c++, opencv, visual-studio-2012

I've tried to install OpenCV for VS2012, but unfortunately all I got was (exactly) 2584 build errors and no working library.

So my question is simple: **is it possible to use OpenCV (e.g. 2.4.0) under VisualStudio 2012** ? If so, can I use the VC++ 11.0 compiler?

Comment: I've written a [blog post](http://karanjthakkar.wordpress.com/2012/11/21/usin-opencv-2-4-2-with-visual-studio-2012-on-windows-7-64-bit/) which might help you to use OpenCV with Visual Studio 2012. See if it works for you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure if you can successfully build OpenCV for VS 2012, (haven't seen any successful case yet), but surely you can build it with VS 2010 easily. (check [this reference](http://jepsonsblog.blogspot.in/2012/07/installation-guide-opencv-24-with.html))

Also, check [this article](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_visual_studio_Opencv/windows_visual_studio_Opencv.html#how-to-build-applications-with-opencv-inside-the-microsoft-visual-studio) which explains how to build applications with OpenCV inside VS

Comment: Well, I've managed it to work thanks to you ;-) The first link (http://jepsonsblog.blogspot.in/2012/07/installation-guide-opencv-24-with.html) is very very useful. **Don't read any official manuals** since they are reeeaaly out of date.

Comment: For reference: with opencv now at 2.4.9 you can build using visual studio 2012.